# Getting "TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract." when importing contracts

Tags: solidity

I have a contract `Example`, which imports another contract `Another`. When I try to import the contract and declare it in the code like this:

```
import './Another.sol'

contract Example {

    Another Another;

}
```

I get the above type error. The contract definitely exists, and I've done this pattern before, why am I getting this type error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable name cannot be the same as the contract name. So the instance of `Another` cannot be named `Another`, you must call it `another`, or something else, like `anotherInstance`. Annoying problem that I ran into that wasn't documented, so I decided to put this up.