# Error when compiling

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm using the latest version of Truffle. When I try to compile my contract I get this error. I don't know what is happening

```
/home/josue/Desktop/blockchain/ebay/contracts/Migrations.sol:20:5: TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    ^--------^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Node v11.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your contract's code contains, but I found this: [Getting "TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract." when importing contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39012/getting-typeerror-name-has-to-refer-to-a-struct-enum-or-contract-when-impor?rq=1)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be flagged as a duplicate. Have a look over here:

[TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract when compiling a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66328/typeerror-name-has-to-refer-to-a-struct-enum-or-contract-when-compiling-a-cont)

The Migrations contract is generated automatically with `truffle init` and it is always compatible with the version of truffle *at that time*.

I'm guessing someone ran `truffle init` on an older Truffle, and now you're trying to run with a 0.5.0 compiler (newer).

That means the contracts have to be refactored for Solidity 0.5.0. Alternatively, you could use truffle's new compiler version selector feature to force an older compiler into the picture.

Hope it helps.