# TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract when compiling a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I'm getting a weird error while compiling a contract in Solidity, I think it's because I'm using Solidity v0.5.0 and it was written with a previous version. Here's the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Migrations {
    address public owner;
    uint public last_completed_migration;

    modifier restricted() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }

    function Migrations() {
         owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setCompleted(uint completed) restricted {
        last_completed_migration = completed;
    }

    function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
        Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
        upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
    }
}
```

To be specific the compiler returns:

```
TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
```

underling the first appearance of Migrations.

Where's the problem in this?

Comment: If you're using Solidity 0.5.0, then why does your code begin with `pragma solidity ^0.4.2`?

Comment: Because when I first studied this code that was the version being used. I know have changed it v0.5.0 but the error stays

Comment: It does not matter. ^ means “after or equal this compiler version”. So 0.5.0 is fine

Comment: P.s.: after you changed using constructor, use at least a pragma solidity ^0.4.24 or so... 

Answer (score 2):

There are other issues to get a clean compile with 0.5.0.

Here is an untested hack that compiles cleanly. I feel like I should point out that `Migrations` should always compile with the corresponding Truffle that created it (using `truffle init`), so this sort of hack shouldn't be necessary.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Migrations {

    address public owner;
    uint public last_completed_migration;

    modifier restricted() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
        last_completed_migration = completed;
    }

    function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
        Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
        upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, thanks. Only problem now is that I'm getting: TypeError: Event invocations have to be prefixed by "emit".
        votedEvent(_candidateId);
        ^----------------------^
which is a method called in another contract

Comment: You'll have minor issues with all of your contracts. The visibility of constructors and other functions, for example. Needs `public` where the old code might be silent on the matter. Constructor names, `emit`, etc. See here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html

Comment: Man: we helped a lot, but please do not ask here without reading the docs! It is not a good habit! Good luck, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the

```
function Migrations...
```

with

```
constructor...
```

In 0.5.0 there is no more the use of a function with the same name of the contract as constructor